# how to import font laravel markdown?

Tags: laravel

Good morning, maybe someone knows how to import a font in the `default.css` file, is it to change the font type that is sent in the emails generated by Markdown? I'm trying it in these two ways but it does not change. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your @font-face url looks like it is not going to work, you cant run php in css file

Change it to :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: galano;
  src: url('../fonts/GalanoGrotesqueMedium.otf');
}
```

This will depend on your folder structure but I am guessing fonts dir is inside the public folder

--Edit-- 
There is no default way to render mail in 5.4 you can follow this guide https://medium.com/@oscarmwana/preview-your-notification-emails-in-laravel-5-4-f30458d6ce4b

```
// routes/web.php

$this->get(‘preview-notification’, function () {

    $message = (new \App\Notifications\TestNotification())->toMail('test@email.com');
    $markdown = new \Illuminate\Mail\Markdown(view(), config(‘mail.markdown’));

    return $markdown->render(‘vendor.notifications.email’, $message->toArray());
});
```

Comment: I tried it that way, too, but without results. The emails are sent with a different font. Any other idea?

Comment: @diego Bsc Have you tried rendering the mail and checking what css classes you are getting in the browser? use 'return (new App\Mail\InvoicePaid($invoice))->render();'

Comment: hello Marcus, maybe you know how I can render the mail in laravel 5.4 to verify what you tell me. I have searched for information about that but only find for laravel 5.5

Comment: @Diego I did not realize you were using 5.4, I updated my answer with a guide to accomplish this in 5.4.

Comment: thanks Marcurs, 
in effect the mail is rendered, and in the view I can see the css where I see that there is the name of the font, but in the view that font is not shown. It is as if the css does not find the font and puts one by default. The problem is how I call my font from the css. I am currently calling her in this way : font-family: galano;
    src: url("//{{ public_path('storage/fonts/'.GalanoGrotesqueMedium.otf)}}");